# Selecting Json Property based on string parameter

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am working with [Json.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and following is my JsonResponse Class

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports AustinHarris.JsonRpc

Public Class JsonResponse
    Inherits AustinHarris.JsonRpc.JsonResponse
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="token")> Public Property token As String
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="product")> Public Property product As String
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="status")> Public Property status As String
End Class
```

As you can see I have some additional custom properties for my Json Object. I am using below code to create my Json Object.

```
jsonrpc_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JsonResponse)(json_string)
```

Finally I have a JsonObject with token, product and status as its properties. Now what I want to do is access these properties using string as parameter e.g.

```
MsgBox ("This is my token: " & jsonrpc_response("token"))
MsgBox ("This is my product: " & jsonrpc_response("product"))
```

However this is not working as these properties cannot be accessed in this fashion. How do I access property based on string as property name parameter?

Comment: once you deserialize, wouldnt it be `jsonrpc_response.Token`?  that is how JsonResponse appears to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, following function added to JsonResponse Class works perfect!

```
Public Function GetPropValue(src As Object, propName As String) As Object
        Return src.[GetType]().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, Nothing)
End Function
```

Thus,

```
MsgBox("This is my token: " & jsonrpc_response.GetPropValue(jsonrpc_response, "token"))
```

Comment: there is no need for reflection.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` would provide a keyed collection